# What triggers the rain?

Tags: rain-world

I've read conflicting interpretations online on what causes the crushing rain to pour. Does it happen about every 15 minutes no matter what the player does? Is it caused by hibernation and/or does hibernation stave it off? Is it possible to not hibernate long enough?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the rain occurs on a timer that you can view on your map. See [this article](http://www.pcgamer.com/rain-world-hints-tips/):

> Bring up your map. **The little dots around the rung / season meter in the bottom left of the screen counts down to when it will start raining.** Keep an eye on it.

I'm not sure exactly how long this timer lasts, but it seems like it is pretty consistent. Based on articles like [this one](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2017/03/27/rain-world-review/), it seems that the rain comes at a regular interval and doesn't appear to be affected by any other factors.

> This comes periodically. I never timed it, but it felt like **maybe every fifteen minutes or so**.

As an aside, I found articles mentioning the rain coming after "spending too long without hibernating," like [this IGN review](http://m.ign.com/articles/2017/03/27/rain-world-review), but I believe the author was referring to the fact that you're required to hibernate on a regular interval lest you die to the rain.