# Is it possible to survive the rain?

Tags: rain-world

When it [downpours](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/304420/21177), does the rain ever let up? Or does it completely flood the screen until the slugcat dies? Is reaching the hibernation point the only way to survive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on multiple articles that I've been looking at, it seems like reaching a hibernation point is the only way not to die when it begins to downpour.

From [this review](https://www.destructoid.com/review-rain-world-427826.phtml):

> Rain World is beset with regular monsoon downpours that punctuate your exploratory efforts every 15 or 20 minutes or so. These storms drive down rain with such unrelenting force and volume that it's fatal to stand exposed to them, while also quickly flooding any subterranean shelter you might be hiding in. **If you're not in a safe, air-locked hibernation cubby when the water begin to rise, you're dead.**

And from [this article](http://www.pushsquare.com/reviews/ps4/rain_world):

> Periodically, a downpour of rain starts to fill up the map and in these instances, it's up to you to navigate Slugcat to select safe rooms, where you can ride out the storm. **To simplify it, it almost functions like a calendar. Each safe room brings you to the next day, as Slugcat hibernates** – so long as you have eaten enough food that is.

Thus, it appears the only way to survive when it downpours is to make it to a hibernation point in time, otherwise you're dead.